# How to develop the code to save more than word in the selected file?

Tags: java, file, save

The goal of my program is to give the user the opportunity to add something in a new or old file.

Because of my code the user can add only one word to the file. 
I wrote down where the problem is.
I do not know how to make the saving of the words in the file unlimited.
I tried with a for loop... Unfortunately it did not make any sense.

```
public class AddAndSave {


private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static Formatter formatter = null;
    private static Scanner reader;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("In which file do you want to add?");
        String fileName = scanner.next();
        File myFile = new File("C://Meine Dateien// " + fileName + ".txt");

        if (myFile.exists() == true) {
            try {
                reader = new Scanner(myFile);
                String fileContent = "";

                while (reader.hasNext() == true) {
                    fileContent = fileContent + reader.next();
                }
                formatter = new Formatter(myFile);
                formatter.format("%s", fileContent + "  ");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            try {
                formatter = new Formatter(myFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("What do you want to add?");
        String newInput = scanner.next();//hier is the problem


        formatter.format("%s", newInput);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Finish! Thank you for using our programm!");
        formatter.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just put the last prompt and format in a loop. What are you stuck on specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the fact that you are utilizing the wrong Scanner method for retrieving String line data from both **file** and **User**.

Use the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method instead of the [Scanner#next()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) method **and** use it in conjunction with the [Scanner#HasNextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextline.htm) method in your **while** loop condition (instead of the [Scanner#hasNext()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm) method):

```
String newInput = scanner.nextLine();
```

Use the **Scanner#nextLine()** method where you prompt for a file name and prompt for what to add to file!. Also use it within your **while** loop for reading the file (in conjuction with the **Scanner#hasNextLine()** method). Carefully read about the differences between all these methods!

**Scanner#hasNext()** and **Scanner#next()** methods are more geared towords Token (word) based situations (one word at a time) whereas the **Scanner#hasNextLine()** and **Scanner#nextLine()** methods are used for entire string lines. This is what I believe you *really* want.

> Other Notes:

You may want to remove the white-space after your last forward slashes (//):

```
"C://Meine Dateien// " + fileName + ".txt";
```

unless of course you want t0 add a white-space at the beginning of every every name for every file created by your application.

When using boolean variables in conditions such as those in **if** statements, you can just use:

```
if (myFile.exists()) {   // IF true
```

instead of:

```
if (myFile.exists() == true) {  // IF true
```

and:

```
if (!myFile.exists()) {   // IF false
```

instead of:

```
if (myFile.exists() == false) {  // IF false
```

Either way works just fine but you will later find that the shorter way is less prone to errors due to typo's and I think it's easier to read but that's just my opinion.

Don't forget to close your file **reader**. Use [**Try With Resources**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html) to take care of this sort of thing for you with regards to both your reader and writer.